# How can I transfer values of an int and string from one program to another in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, textfield, transfer

Ok so In my code I'm asking the user for their name and asking them to click one of 3 buttons which gives a variable a corresponding value. Now in another program I want to call upon this program and then pretty much display the string and use the int value for a certain purpose.

```
public class MainMenuofgame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton slow, medium, fast;
    JLabel pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4;
    JTextField username;
    Container frame;

    static String name;
    static int xspeed = 0;          

    public MainMenuofgame() { 
            super ("Main Menu of Rocket Launch");
            frame = getContentPane ();
            frame.setLayout (null);

            pic1 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("welcome.png"));

            pic2  = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("name.png"));

            pic3 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("speed.png"));

            pic4 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("backgnd.jpg"));

            username = new JTextField ();

            slow = new JButton("Slow");
            //  slow.setActionCommand("slowspeed");
            slow.addActionListener (this);

            medium = new JButton("Medium");
            // medium.setActionCommand("mediumspeed");
            medium.addActionListener (this);

            fast = new JButton("Fast");
            // fast.setActionCommand("fastspeed");
            fast.addActionListener (this);

            pic1.setBounds (30,50, 525, 173);//welcome
            pic2.setBounds (100,230,212,73);//name
            pic3.setBounds (80,350,428,84);//speed

            username.setBounds(310,255,150,30);

            slow.setBounds (100,450,100,100);
            medium.setBounds (250,450,100,100);
            fast.setBounds (400,450,100,100);
            //background bound goes in the end 
            pic4.setBounds (0,0, 600,900);

            frame.add (pic1);

            frame.add (pic2);

            frame.add (pic3);

            frame.add (username);

            frame.add (slow);

            frame.add (medium);

            frame.add (fast);    

            frame.add (pic4);


            setSize(600, 900);
            setVisible (true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){

            String name = username.getText();

            if (evt.getSource () == slow)
            {
                    xspeed = 1;
            }
            else if(evt.getSource () == medium)
            {
                    xspeed = 5;
            }
            else 
            {
                    xspeed = 10;
            }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            new MainMenuofgame ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Save it to file in the first program, then read the file in the second?

Comment: could you use an example to explain? @Carcigenicate

Comment: You have a number you want to transfer between programs? Write the number to a file in the first program, then I'm the second program, read the file you just saved. I'm on my phone, so I can't really type of an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um... really all I needed to do was call upon my variable that I wanted to store my data in and then well... store it. This is done in the If statement at the bottom. Thanks everyone for helping but honestly most of your answers rised more questions than answered mine and just confused me but I figured it out so thanks anyways :)

```
public class MainMenuofgame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton slow, medium, fast;
    JLabel pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4;
    JTextField username;
    Container frame;

    static String name;
    static int xspeed = 0;          

    public MainMenuofgame() { 
            super ("Main Menu of Rocket Launch");
            frame = getContentPane ();
            frame.setLayout (null);

            pic1 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("welcome.png"));

            pic2  = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("name.png"));

            pic3 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("speed.png"));

            pic4 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("backgnd.jpg"));

            username = new JTextField ();

            slow = new JButton("Slow");
            //  slow.setActionCommand("slowspeed");
            slow.addActionListener (this);

            medium = new JButton("Medium");
            // medium.setActionCommand("mediumspeed");
            medium.addActionListener (this);

            fast = new JButton("Fast");
            // fast.setActionCommand("fastspeed");
            fast.addActionListener (this);

            pic1.setBounds (30,50, 525, 173);//welcome
            pic2.setBounds (100,230,212,73);//name
            pic3.setBounds (80,350,428,84);//speed

            username.setBounds(310,255,150,30);

            slow.setBounds (100,450,100,100);
            medium.setBounds (250,450,100,100);
            fast.setBounds (400,450,100,100);
            //background bound goes in the end 
            pic4.setBounds (0,0, 600,900);

            frame.add (pic1);

            frame.add (pic2);

            frame.add (pic3);

            frame.add (username);

            frame.add (slow);

            frame.add (medium);

            frame.add (fast);    

            frame.add (pic4);


            setSize(600, 900);
            setVisible (true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){

            String name = username.getText();
            Rocketlaunch.name = name;

            if (evt.getSource () == slow)
            {
                    Rocketlaunch.moveSpeed = 1;
                    Rocketlaunch.speed = "Slow";
                    setVisible (false);
            }
            else if(evt.getSource () == medium)
            {
                    Rocketlaunch.moveSpeed = 5;
                    Rocketlaunch.speed = "Medium";
                    setVisible (false);
            }
            else 
            {
                    Rocketlaunch.moveSpeed = 10;
                    Rocketlaunch.speed = "Fast";
                    setVisible (false);
            }

            new Rocketlaunch();

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            new MainMenuofgame ();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you describe is not in fact the *"transfer values of an int and string from one program to another in Java"*, but rather much more simply the transfer of data from one object to another, here the objects are represented by GUI components. Don't create two separate programs, but rather create separate objects that interact in a meaningful way. That is the essence of OOPs with Java. The simplest solution is to have the main application display the sub-application's GUI within a modal dialog such as a modal JDialog, and then once the dialog has been dealt with (i.e., is no longer visible) then the main program/object queries the dialog for the state of its components -- the data that was entered.

Also you are painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MenuDemoMainPanel extends JPanel {
    private MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
    private JDialog menuDialog = null;
    private String name;
    private Speed speed;
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField speedField = new JTextField(10);

    public MenuDemoMainPanel() {

        // these fields are for display only and should not allow user
        // interaction
        nameField.setFocusable(false);
        speedField.setFocusable(false);

        // not kosher to set this directly, per kleopatra, but oh well
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        // simple demo GUI -- add components
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(nameField);
        add(new JLabel("Speed:"));
        add(speedField);
        add(new JButton(new GetNameAndSpeedAction("Get Name And Speed")));
    }

    // action for JButton that displays the menuDialog JDialog
    private class GetNameAndSpeedAction extends AbstractAction {
        public GetNameAndSpeedAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (menuDialog == null) {
                // if the menu dialog has not been created yet -- create it
                Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MenuDemoMainPanel.this);
                menuDialog = new JDialog(win, "Menu", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                menuDialog.add(menuPanel);
                menuDialog.pack();
                menuDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
            }

            // display the menu JDialog
            menuDialog.setVisible(true);

            // this code is called only when the dialog is no longer visible
            // query the dialog for the state it holds
            name = menuPanel.getNameText();
            speed = menuPanel.getSpeed();

            // and display the state in the main GUI
            if (name != null && speed != null) {
                nameField.setText(name);
                speedField.setText(speed.getText());
            }

        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // create the main GUI JPanel
        MenuDemoMainPanel mainPanel = new MenuDemoMainPanel();

        // then create an application GUI 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu Demo -- Main GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel); // place the main panel into the GUI

        // and pack and display it:
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

// JPanel to hold menu dialog components
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MenuPanel extends JPanel {
    private JComboBox<Speed> speedCombo = new JComboBox<>(Speed.values());
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);

    public MenuPanel() {
        speedCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(nameField);
        add(new JLabel("Speed:"));
        add(speedCombo);
        add(new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit")));
    }

    // allow outside classes to query the nameField JTextField's state
    public String getNameText() {
        return nameField.getText();
    }

    // allow outside classes to query the speedCombo JComboBox's state
    public Speed getSpeed() {
        return (Speed) speedCombo.getSelectedItem();
    }

    // Action for JButton that submits the dialog to the main GUI
    private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SubmitAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // if the data is not all entered or selected
            if (nameField.getText().trim().isEmpty() || speedCombo.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                Component comp = MenuPanel.this;
                String msg = "You must enter your name and select a speed";
                String title = "Invalid Data";
                int msgType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
                // warn the user and leave this dialog still visible
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comp, msg, title, msgType);
            } else {

                // otherwise dispose of this dialog and thereby pass control
                // back to the main application / GUI
                Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MenuPanel.this);
                win.dispose();
            }
        }

    }
}

// an enum to encapsulate possible game speeds
enum Speed {
    SLOW("Slow"), MEDIUM("Medium"), FAST("Fast");
    private String text;

    private Speed(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: um I found an easier way to do this and I put it as an answer, could you please look at it and maybe give some kind of feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There are one of two ways that come to mind on how to transfer information from one program to another...

1. Client-Server applications

This requires you to have a third application running accepting information from each of the other two application (clients) through a socket. For further information Google "Client-Server applications in Java"

2. Have a text file passing information

To do this you should have a text file that one application stores information in and the other application just simply reads it... This is an easier solution but is less of a learning experience. Here is example code.

Application 1:

```
private void storeMessage(String msg){
    File centralFile = new File("path to your file");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(centralFile));
    writer.write(msg);
    writer.close();
}
```

Application 2:

```
private String getMessage(){
    File centralFile = new File("path to your file");
    String msg = "";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(centralFile));
    while (reader.hasNextLine()){
        msg += reader.nextLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    return msg;
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: um right now Im just going for the easy one because im short on time but do you know what is it called to store data in a text file and to read data from a text file so that I can research how to do that @paul

Comment: If you still don't understand search "how to write to a text file in Java" and "how to read text from a file in Java"

Comment: could you be more lenient please and tell me how can I do this in my code?

Comment: Copy and past these method into your applications, Create a file at a specified location and replace "your file path here" with that path (i.e. C:\files\myFile.txt) and call them as needed. The code I have given is complete other than the file path is not specified. The only thing you have to do is figure out how to tell when to call the methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you please explain to me how do I call the dependent data-requesting gui from the main gui as a dialog?